# Automation Testing using selenium webDriver on a javaScript based application

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, protractor, uiautomation

I am having a JavaScript-based application to automate using Selenium  WebDriver.

Can I automate a Javascript based application using Java with Selenium WebDriver OR do I have to use protractor (Javascript based testing tool)?

What are the main problems and challenges of using Java versus using a Javascript based test tool?

Answer (score 1):

WebDriver is a way to automate browsers, it doesnt really matter which language binding you use to implement WebDriver testcases, it is possible with all languages (e.g. C#, Python, Ruby, Java, JavaScript, etc..). **All** web applications use HTML, CSS and **JavaScript**. So it is all the same.

Protractor makes it easier to automate an application developed in **Angular**, not JavaScript per se.

I would write the WebDriver tests in a programming language nearby developers program, so that they can help building and also maintain the tests as they are adding features to the application. If you use a language they do not know they will probably never assist the automators.

- JavaScript main issue is that its nature is [asynchronous](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff), which makes it a bit more complex in some situations.
- Java's main issue is that it is Java ;-)